# Resolve FB GraphAPI picture call to the final URL

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application that displays a users/friends photos. For the most part I can pull photos from the album, however for user/album cover photos, all that is given is the object ID for which the following URL provides the image:

`https://graph.facebook.com/1015146931380136/picture?access_token=ABCDEFG&type=picture`

Which when viewed redirects the user to the image file itself such as:

`https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/420455_1015146931380136_78924167_s.jpg`

My question is, is there a Pythonic or GraphAPI method to resolve the final image path an avoid sending the Access Token to the end user?

Comment: I'm wondering, is there a real need to restrict the end user from seeing their own access_token? I feel like if it's possible to only hold it server-side I should probably do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The facebook graph api urls do a 302 redirect to the CDN url actually having the user avatar.
You can easily find it using `urllib2`

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = "http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture"
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url)
>>> res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> finalUrl = res.geturl()
>>> finalUrl
'http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/157340_4_3955636_q.jpg'
```

Or call the JSON version of Graph api for picture :

http://graph.facebook.com/4/?fields=picture&type=large

Decode it, and get the `url` :

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "url": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/157340_4_3955636_q.jpg",
         "is_silhouette": false
      }
   }
}
```

Tips:

1. Do not use https where http can work, it works in avatar api. http is faster.
2. You do not need access_token to query graph api for pictures,it works without access_token as well.

Answer (score 2):

to get the actual image url for cover photos, first you can make facebook api call to get the cover picture then extract `url` field, with `PHP` I do something like:

```
$cover = $facebook->api("$album_id?fields=picture&access_token=ABVHDG");
$cover_url = $cover['picture']['data']['url']; //this $cover_url is image file itself from host fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Make a Graph API call like this and you get the real URL:

> https://graph.facebook.com/[fbid]?fields=picture

Btw, you don´t need an access token for this.

Comment: It's not just User cover_photo, but album cover_photo as well. For instance, here's an album I've created which only resolves with an access_token: https://graph.facebook.com/10152205730015184/picture